# How do I query mongodb with MID

Tags: mongodb

I have query something as SQL's like query:

```
select * from users where MID(nama,1,2)='A'
```

How to do the same in mongodb? I can't find a operator for like in the documentation.

Comment: check **[$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)**

Comment: ... and [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following aggregation query:

```
db.users.aggregate([{$project: { _id: 0, name: { $substr: [ "$name", 0, 1 ]}}}])
```

This uses the projections and substring:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/

For example:

```
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "test", "ok" : 1 }
> db.users.save({"name": "Kevin"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.users.save({"name": "Matt"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.users.save({"name": "Sakis"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.users.save({"name": "Lee"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
> db.users.aggregate([{$project: { _id: 0, name: { $substr: [ "$name", 0, 1 ]}}}])
{ "name" : "K" }
{ "name" : "M" }
{ "name" : "S" }
{ "name" : "L" }
```